# Recover cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie using the following method

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

setCookie("cicloavaliacao", idCicloAvaliacao, 1);
```

In image bellow, I created a cookie called `cicloavaliacao`

[image]

But when I try to recover this cookie using `document.cookie`, ir returns a empty string.

Why this is happen or what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: is it there on page refresh?

Comment: @iam-decoder yes, I check it, but document.cookie always return empty string

Comment: How are you calling `setCookie()`? What value are you passing for `exdays`?

Comment: @PaulRoub I updated my question with the method calling

Comment: I try your code in fiddle and it works if variable idCicloAvaliacao is set. So problem have to be in this variable.